# Detach nodejs x11 application from the console with JavaScript

Tags: linux, node.js, terminal, x11

While using `x11` module for `node.js`, application must be detached from the console from within the application. It is possible to start `node` in background with `node myapp.js > /dev/null &` but how to detach from within the program itself?

Comment: why should it be detached? I saw quite a lot of x11 apps that don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm author of node-x11, but your questions seems to be generic and not related to x11.

Example where you might want to detach from terminal is implementing xclip in js ( see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254114/xclip-does-not-terminate-when-tracing-it/19260314#19260314) )

Lots of possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service) tl;dr - if you don't want to detach it from outside with `nohup` you can use module like [daemon](https://github.com/indexzero/daemon.node)