# passthru hangs if the executed command writes to the clipboard

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line-interface, clipboard

Put this in a file "a.php" and execute it. It works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$p = popen('xclip -i -selection clipboard', 'w');
fwrite($p, 'Hello Word');
pclose($p);
```

Now make a file "b.php" and execute it:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
passthru('./a.php');
```

It hangs forever. Why?

(If you do not have xclip, you can install it with apt-get install xclip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"xclip -i -selection clipboard > /dev/null"
should fix it

xclip doesn't close the STDOUT.

related to: [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254114/xclip-does-not-terminate-when-tracing-it)