# Emacs shell-command with xclip hangs when copying to clipboard

Tags: shell, emacs, xclip

I'm encountering an issue where running `xclip` through `shell-command` in Emacs to copy text to the clipboard hangs. Here's the minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem:

```lisp
(shell-command "echo foobar | xclip -selection clipboard")
```

When I execute this, Emacs freezes. Running the same xclip command directly in a terminal works without any issues.

I've tried various workarounds, such as using the -i option with xclip, redirecting stderr to /dev/null and executing xclip in the background with nohup and &, but none have resolved the issue.

I'm running Emacs on Manjaro with Emacs 29.1. Any insights or solutions to prevent Emacs from hanging when using xclip in this way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: xclip doesn't really exit when run from terminal, it forks to the background. I'm not sure how emacs handles this. look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154953/4437190

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it. Seems like it will not be a simple problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious and played a bit with this problem.  Using `nohup` in conjunction with `shell-command` seems to do what you want:

```lisp
(shell-command 
  "echo nowitworks | nohup xclip -selection clipboard > /dev/null 2>&1")
```

`nohup` would normaly create a file `nohup.out`, the redirections are there to prevent that.